# Decrypting RSA data in .NET with only a few values

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsa

I'm using the Javascript implementation of RSA [from this webpage](http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/rsa/rsa-test.htm), and I've generated my keypair there. As such, I have `p`, `q`, the public exponent, the public modulo, the private exponent and the private inverse.

How can I use .NET's `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to decrypt the ciphertext with only these values? The .NET docs list three other fields; `DP`, `DQ` and `InverseQ` which I'm not sure how to supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two representations for an RSA private key (cf [PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125)).

The first representation consists of the pair (n, d), the second representation consists of a quintuple (p, q, dP, dQ, qInv). The public key is represented as (n, e).

- n is the public modulus
- p and q are the two primes
- d is the private exponent
- e is the public exponent
- dP is p's Chinese Remainder Theorem coefficient ( e · dP ≡ 1 (mod (p – 1)) )
- dQ is q's CRT coefficient ( e · dQ ≡ 1 (mod (q – 1)) )
- qInv is a CRT coefficient, a positive integer less than p such that
  q · qInv ≡ 1 (mod p)

Each of the two private key representation is "complete", i.e. you only need one of them to be able to perform RSA computations. Since you are in possession of everything that is necessary for the first representation, it suffices to only set these parameters (i.e. n, p, q, e, d) on your `RSAParameters` instance and omit the rest.

Comment: The Javascript key generator creates an array of 28 bit integers. Is it correct to extend them to 32 bits and represent them as little endian when converting them to a byte array?

Comment: To be on the safe side, I'd use BigInteger#Parse(String)?

Answer (score 1):

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#A_worked_example) seems to contain instructions on how to calculate these parameters, namely

> The values dp, dq and qInv, which are part of the private key are computed as follows:
>
> ```
> dp = d mod (p − 1)
> dq = d mod (q − 1)
> qInv = q^−1 mod p
> ```